# Резервное копирование в PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, резервное-копирование

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста с проблемой: СУБД отказывается делать резервную копию.
Делаю все как полагается:
Открываю меню создания бэкапа, задаю параметры, нажимаю "Резервное копирование", а оно говорит -"БД не существует" Что?!
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать копию, как обойти этот глюк (3 попытки):

> C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin\pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password  --format directory --section pre-data --section data --section post-data --encoding UTF8 --verbose --file "C:\Users\Expo1on\Desktop\Агро-Сервис.backup" "Агро-Сервис"
>   pg_dump: [каталоговый архиватор] создать каталог "C:\Users\Expo1on\Desktop\Агро-Сервис.backup" не удалось: File exists
>   Процесс вернул код выхода 1.
>   C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin\pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password  --format directory --section pre-data --section data --section post-data --encoding UTF8 --verbose --file "C:\Users\Expo1on\Desktop\Агро-Сервис.backup" "Агро-Сервис"
>   pg_dump: [каталоговый архиватор] создать каталог "C:\Users\Expo1on\Desktop\Агро-Сервис.backup" не удалось: File exists
>   Процесс вернул код выхода 1.
>   C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin\pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password  --format directory --section pre-data --section data --section post-data --encoding UTF8 --verbose --file "C:\Users\Expo1on\Desktop\Агро-Сервис.backup" "Агро-Сервис"
>   pg_dump: [архиватор (БД)] не удалось подключиться к базе "Агро-Сервис": ВАЖНО:  база данных "Агро-Сервис" не существует
>   Процесс вернул код выхода 1.

Answer (score 1):

А версия какая?

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой, танцы с бубном не помогли, сделал бекап при помощи `pg_basebackup`.

```
backup@backup ~ $ pg_basebackup -x -h db01.example.com -U backup -D /backup
```

Вот есть еще статейка [backup Postgressql](http://habrahabr.ru/post/222311/)